# How to create trigger in oracle database so that future date cannot set?

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I have a column 'patient_dob' in 'patient' table. Now I want to create a trigger in oracle database so that patient cannot set future date as their birth date. So I ave write the following query:

```
create or replace trigger test_trigger
before insert
on employees
for each row 
BEGIN
IF patient_dob > sysdate
   THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20950, 'date error');
END IF;
END;
```

but the code is not working. Can anyone tell me how to create a trigger to perform the above functionality?
Thanks

Comment: define "not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `new` to identify the column:

```
create or replace trigger test_trigger
before insert
on employees
for each row 
BEGIN
    IF :new.patient_dob > sysdate THEN
-------^
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20950, 'date error');
    END IF;
END;
```